# What are you supposed to return from a lambda trigger function of type "Post confirmation trigger" in c#?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am working on creating a user record in my database that corresponds to a user in my cognito pool. The code works fine, but in the fronted i keep receiving an error saying "Unrecognizable lambda output"

I have tried returning the context as I have seen examples of in js but all i get is the same error.

```
public ILambdaContext Get(CognitoPostConfirmation cognitoPostConfirmation, ILambdaContext context)
{

    var newUser = {name = "name"};

    try
    {
        \_collection.InsertOne(newUser);
    }
    catch
    {
        context.Logger.LogInformation("Failed to ");
    }

    return context;
}
```

I tried returning both the following object or a string but same problem:

```
public class EventResponse
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public object Body { get; set; }
}
```

What are you supposed to return from this type of lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to return the event so in this case `return cognitoPostConfirmation` did the trick. Thought I had tried that already but apparently not